# How to reverse node order in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to build a simple task flow in graphviz. Below is my code

```
digraph R {

node [shape=record; fontname=Ariel];
overlap=false;
rankdir="LR";


box2 [label="Any blocking? "]; 
box3 [label="Any open points?"]; 
box4 [label="cleared?"]; 
box5 [label="cleared?"];


node [shape=circle; fixedsize=true; width=1.2;fillcolor="#bad9ff"; style="filled"];
S1 [label="New"];
 


node [shape=circle; fixedsize=true; width=1.2;fillcolor="yellow"; style="filled"];
S2 [label="InProgress"]; 

node [shape=circle; fixedsize=true; width=1.2; fillcolor="#8fff4f"; style="filled"];
S5 [label="Closed"]; 

node [shape=circle; fixedsize=true; width=1.2; fillcolor="#ff4f69"; fontcolor="white"; style="filled"];
S3 [label="On hold"]; S4 [label="Need \n Clarification"];



S1 -> S2
S2 -> S5

S2 -> box3
box3 -> S4
S4 -> box5
box5 -> S2

S2 -> box2
box2 -> S3
S3 -> box4
box4 -> S2


labelloc="t";
label="Task Flow";
fontsize="20";
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

I could not find a way to make the **New** node to start left, and **Closed** node to come to the right end. I tried pin, and pos but for both nodes but in vain. I used neato engine.

Comment: Note that rankdir (all rank-related attributes) are ignored by neato (dot only).  That is not the problem here, just a comment about your use of rankdir.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an embarrassing kludge solution, but it works.  Swap labels & arrow direction, like so:

```
digraph R {

node [shape=record; fontname=Ariel];
overlap=false;
//rankdir="LR";

box2 [label="Any blocking? "]; 
box3 [label="Any open points?"]; 
box4 [label="cleared?"]; 
box5 [label="cleared?"];

node [shape=circle; fixedsize=true; width=1.2;fillcolor="#bad9ff"; style="filled"];
S1 [label="Closed"]; // [label="New"]; // kludge

node [shape=circle; fixedsize=true; width=1.2;fillcolor="yellow"; style="filled"];
S2 [label="InProgress"]; 

node [shape=circle; fixedsize=true; width=1.2; fillcolor="#8fff4f"; style="filled"];
S5 [label="New"]; //  [label="Closed"];  // kludge

node [shape=circle; fixedsize=true; width=1.2; fillcolor="#ff4f69"; fontcolor="white"; style="filled"];
S3 [label="On hold"]; S4 [label="Need \n Clarification"];

S1 -> S2 -> S5 [dir=back]  //kludge

S2 -> box3
box3 -> S4
S4 -> box5
box5 -> S2
S2 -> box2
box2 -> S3
S3 -> box4
box4 -> S2
labelloc="t";
label="Task Flow";
fontsize="20";
}
```

[image]